# Jquery: .show() div functionality not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have 2 'draggable' divs and 2 'droppable' divs. Draggable1 div should be accepted by droppable1 div and so on. This functionality works.
If draggable1 div is is dropped, it displays another 'success' div having id 'hide'. However, when I try to check if both draggables have been dropped respectively, it doesn't show the new 'success' div having id 'hide2' anymore.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g27t7hey/

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="draggables" id="draggable1"></div><br>
<div class="draggables" id="draggable2"></div><br>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
<div class="droppables" id="droppable1"></div>
<div class="droppables" id="droppable2"></div>
</div>

<div id="hide" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="hide2" style="display:none"></div>
```

Above is the html code. CSS and JS code are provided in the fiddle.

I would like to know why it isn't working for 2 divs together? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
Taking T J's answer and his updated code into consideration, I further updated the code to show what I was exactly looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/g27t7hey/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has statements like this:

```
 else if (draggableID=='draggable1' && droppableID=='droppable1' && draggableID=='draggable2' && droppableID=='droppable2')
```

I'm not sure what you were thinking, but a variable can't have two values at a time.

Either `draggableID` will be `draggable1` or it'll be `draggable2`, So the above will not evaluate to true.

When you drop an element, the callback executes and `draggableID` will be set to the `id` of the dropped element. It doesn't contain any values from the previous invocation of a function.

Also, you seems to be initializing the same elements as `draggable` multiple times. Any options you set in the previous initialization will be overridden by the next initialization.

And you also seems to have a lot of duplicated code.

If I understood correctly, What you're trying to do can be achieved like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#draggable1, #draggable2').draggable({
    containment: 'document',
    revert: function(event, ui) {
      // return boolean
      return !event;
    }
  });
  $('#droppable1,#droppable2').droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    accept: function(draggable) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id').split('droppable')[1];
      var targetId = draggable.attr('id').split('draggable')[1];
      return id == targetId
    },
    drop: leftDrop
  });

  function leftDrop(event, ui) {

    ui.draggable.appendTo(this).position({
      of: $(this),
      my: 'center',
      at: 'center'
    });
    var draggableID = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    if (draggableID == 'draggable1') $('#hide').show();
    if (draggableID == 'draggable2') {
      if ($('#draggable1').parent().is('#droppable1')) $('#hide2').show();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.wrap2 {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  left: 700px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.draggables {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
.droppables {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
#draggable1 {
  background: #003366;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
#draggable2 {
  background: #ffff00;
  top: 160px;
  left: 60px;
}
#droppable1 {
  background: #0000FF;
  top: 200px;
  left: -400px;
}
#droppable2 {
  background: #008080;
  left: -300px;
  top: 200px;
}
#hide {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #00cc00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
}
#hide2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="draggables" id="draggable1"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="draggables" id="draggable2"></div>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="droppables" id="droppable1"></div>
  <div class="droppables" id="droppable2"></div>
</div>
<div id="hide" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="hide2" style="display:none"></div>
```

---

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g27t7hey/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all that explanation! It helped me understand where I was going wrong. You were almost there in terms of understanding what output I was expecting. I have updated the code to show exactly what I was looking for: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g27t7hey/2/).